# IndexError: tuple index out of range when I try to create an executable from a python script using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, tuples, pyinstaller, executable, index-error

I have been trying out an open-sourced personal AI assistant script. The script works fine but I want to create an executable so that I can gift the executable to one of my friends. However, when I try to create the executable using the auto-py-to-exe, it states the below error:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.10.1
Building directory: C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjaw1ky1x
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --no-embed-manifest  "C:/Users/Tarun/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/AI_Ass.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --no-embed-manifest C:/Users/Tarun/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/AI_Ass.py --distpath C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjaw1ky1x\application --workpath C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjaw1ky1x\build --specpath C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjaw1ky1x

42681 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.6
42690 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
42732 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
42744 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjaw1ky1x\AI_Ass.spec
42764 INFO: UPX is not available.
42772 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Tarun\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310']
43887 INFO: checking Analysis
43891 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
43895 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
43915 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
43975 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
54298 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\Tarun\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
54306 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\Tarun\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
57474 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
58088 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
58132 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
58365 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\AI_Ass.py
59641 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\Tarun\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 782, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 714, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjaw1ky1x\AI_Ass.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['C:/Users/Tarun/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/AI_Ass.py'],
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 439, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 265, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2061, in _safe_import_module
    n = self._scan_code(module, co, co_ast)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2645, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode(
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2749, in _scan_bytecode
    for inst in util.iterate_instructions(module_code_object):
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 147, in iterate_instructions
    yield from iterate_instructions(constant)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 139, in iterate_instructions
    yield from get_instructions(code_object)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 338, in _get_instructions_bytes
    argval, argrepr = _get_const_info(arg, constants)
  File "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 292, in _get_const_info
    argval = const_list[const_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

I understand that there is a thread already about similar issue but it still doesn't solve the issue. Hence seeking out help

I really have no idea why is the error occurring and how to resolve it. I am pasting the script below for your reference. Can some one please help? Thank you in advance

```
#importing libraries

import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import time
import subprocess
from   ecapture import ecapture as ec
import wolframalpha
import json
import requests

#setting up speech engine
engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice','voices[1].id')

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
    
#Greet user
def wishMe():
    hour=datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Hello,Good Morning")
        print("Hello,Good Morning")
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Hello,Good Afternoon")
        print("Hello,Good Afternoon")
    else:
        speak("Hello,Good Evening")
        print("Hello,Good Evening")

#Setting up the command function for your AI assistant
def takeCommand():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio=r.listen(source)

        try:
            statement=r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print(f"user said:{statement}\n")

        except Exception as e:
            speak("Pardon me, please say that again")
            return "None"
        return statement

print("Loading your AI personal assistant Friday")
speak("Loading your AI personal assistant Friday")
wishMe()

#main function
if __name__=='__main__':


    while True:
        speak("Tell me how can I help you now?")
        statement = takeCommand().lower()
        if statement==0:
            continue

        if "good bye" in statement or "ok bye" in statement or "stop" in statement:
            speak('your personal assistant Friday is shutting down,Good bye')
            print('your personal assistant Friday is shutting down,Good bye')
            break


        if 'wikipedia' in statement:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            statement =statement.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(statement, sentences=10)
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+ statement)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'open youtube' in statement:
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
        webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab("https://www.youtube.com")
            #webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.youtube.com")
            speak("youtube is open now")
            time.sleep(5)

        elif 'open google' in statement:
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
            speak("Google chrome is open now")
            time.sleep(5)

        elif 'open gmail' in statement:
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("gmail.com")
            speak("Google Mail open now")
            time.sleep(5)
        
        elif 'time' in statement:
            strTime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            speak(f"the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'news' in statement:
            news = webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/headlines")
            speak('Here are some headlines from the Times of India,Happy reading')
            time.sleep(6)

        elif "camera" in statement or "take a photo" in statement:
            ec.capture(0,"robo camera","img.jpg")

        elif 'search' in statement:
            statement = statement.replace("search", "")
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(statement)
            time.sleep(5)

        elif 'who are you' in statement or 'what can you do' in statement:
            speak('I am Friday version 1 point O your personal assistant. I am programmed to minor tasks like'
            'opening youtube,google chrome, gmail and stackoverflow ,predict time,take a photo,search wikipedia,predict weather' 
            'In different cities, get top headline news from times of india and you can ask me computational or geographical questions too!')


        elif "who made you" in statement or "who created you" in statement or "who discovered you" in statement:
            speak("I was built by Mirthula")
            print("I was built by Mirthula")

        elif "log off" in statement or "sign out" in statement:
            speak("Ok , your pc will log off in 10 sec make sure you exit from all applications")
            subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/l"])
            
time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a Python 3.10 issue.
To fix it:
You have to go to the folder "Python310\Lib" and edit the file 'dis.py'.
In the 'dis.py' file you have to find this "def _unpack_opargs" and inside the else statement write a new line with this: "extended_arg = 0", then save the file.

I did something like that:

```
else:
    arg = None
    extended_arg = 0 
yield (i, op, arg)
```

and everything is working fine now.

I found the solution here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue45757
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6301

Comment: That worked. Thanks @MiguelMLR9

Answer (score 12):

Python 3.10.2+ will fix your issue. If you can't wait, add `extended_arg = 0` to line 431 in the `dis.py` module as seen below.

https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c5bfb88eb6f82111bb1603ae9d78d0476b552d66#

If you are like me and installed Python 3.10 from an older version, you may face some other issues due to installing packages at the system level and at the user level. Make sure packages are installed to the intended location.

Comment: I upgraded python to 3.10.2 and it resolved this issue while using pyinstaller

Answer (score 3):

you need to add

```
extended_arg = 0
```

on line number 431 in Lib/dis.py file
please refer
https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c5bfb88eb6f82111bb1603ae9d78d0476b552d66#

Answer (score 2):

```
42681 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.6
42690 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
```

There's the issue. Python 3.10.0 has a bug with PyInstaller 4.6. The problem isn't you or PyInstaller. Try converting it using Python 3.9.7 instead. Ironic, considering 3.10.0 was suppose to be a bugfix update.

Answer (score 0):

use py2exe as an alternate may work sometimes

1. **pip install py2exe**
2. write the following code and save it in somename.py with your file name that needs to be converted as exe in the same file location

   from distutils.core import setup 
   import py2exe
   setup(console=['yourfilename.py'])
3. now go to cmd in the same location and run somename.py file as **python somename.py py2exe**