Unable to create exe file using Python 3.10
IndexError: tuple index out of range
I hope you're doing well. I'm currently facing an issue creating an .exe file using Python 3.10. I've tried multiple methods, including PyInstaller, but I haven't been successful.
Whenever I attempt to create the executable, I encounter an "IndexError: tuple index out of range" error. I've checked my code and dependencies, but I'm still unable to find a solution.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue with Python 3.10? If so, how did you resolve it?
I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on this matter.
I already tried below solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776492/indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-i-try-to-create-an-executable-from-a-p#:~:text=To%20fix%20it%3A%20You%20have,%22%2C%20then%20save%20the%20file.&text=and%20everything%20is%20working%20fine%20now.&text=Python%203.10.

You should add some more info especially after linking the question. Is your traceback the same as the question? Are you above 3.10.2? etc.

@Peter I am facing IndexError: tuple index out of range. While creating exe file using pyinstaller --onefile main.py
